# Image Sequences to video conversion in matlab

Tags: matlab, video-processing

I have to convert image sequences to a video using 'matlab R2010a' version. What function should I use to load images to a video? In 'Matlab R2013a' version, 'writeVideo' is used. What is the related function of 'writeVideo' in 'R2010a' version?

Comment: Do you want to save a video file, or is it enough to play the video?

Answer (score 0):

If your images are created by some Matlab code, then you can always save them as image files (check out the [`print`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html) function), and use some utility (like [VirtualDub](http://www.respower.com/blog/?p=389)) to convert the image files to video.

If it is enough to play the image sequence without saving it, then use the [`movie`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movie.html) function.